# How do you set values for the first time

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I Wonder how you set values that only should be used once, when the application get used for the first time.

This doesn't seems to work. I've it inside my `onCreate`.

```
    // SharedPreferences
    mSharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Setting up the Switches
    mSwitchWork = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchWork);
    mSwitchPrivate = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchPrivate);


    // TODO: ONGOING
    // If its the first time in use it will set the dates to the current Month and year
    Boolean firstTime = mSharedpreferences.getBoolean("isItFirstTime", true);
    if (firstTime){
        // Just values for the first time
        mTravelType = "Private";
        mSwitchPrivate.setChecked(true);
        mSwitchWork.setChecked(false);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isItFirstTime", false);  // Saving Boolean True/False
        // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
        editor.apply(); // commit changes
    }
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. Can you please provide the code where "mSharedpreferences" is initialized?

Comment: What do you mean with "This doesn't seems to work".

Is the code executed always? Or never?

Comment: updated it now, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` has a `contains(String key)` method, which can be used to check if an entry with the given key exists.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

**Example**

```
    mSharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!mSharedpreferences.contains("isItFirstTime")){
// Shared preference not present create it. First time laucnh
}else{
//SharedPreference already present. Read the value and proceed with your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare

SharedPreferences prefs=null;

//define   
prefs = getSharedPreferences("abcdef", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        //first time ..run only one time



    } else {
        //run  
    }
```